Pagestylenumbering
How to remove the style of page from chapter page and let it in the other pages and write the section next to number page as the following images
This is my cood tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1.7cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=2cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{eso-pic}


\begin{document}
gfjhh;jghcgh
\newpage
hguli
\listoffigures
\newpage
fgdytfu
\chapter{cbvjkdljs}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\put(2,28.3){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(A) at([xshift=3.3cm,yshift=-2cm]current page.north west){};
\shade[top color=gray!80!white,bottom color=white]([xshift=0.7cm]A)--+(0.6,0)--+(0.4,0.8)--+(-0.3,0.8)--cycle;
\draw[color=gray!80!white,line width=1.5pt](A)--([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-2cm]current page.north east);
\fill[color=blue](A)--node[yshift=1mm,pos=0.7,above,color=white,font=\large\bfseries]{\thepage}+(0.8,0)--+(1.1,0.8)--+(0.4,0.8)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\put(4,28.55){\bfseries\color{blue}\large\rightmark}
}
\section{title}
text
\newpage
\section{fgdvvth}
\end{document}



Redefine the plain page style e.g. \fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}} or whatever. Chapter pages will automatically use plain. And don't add anything to the shipout picture. Just use fancyhdr's commands.

Do you want something like this? This actually uses fancyhdr rather than just using it to empty the headers and footers. You want to do this with a page style so that e.g. chapters are handled automatically. I've defined mystyle in case you want fancy for something else. This does not touch the standard plain. If you want to change that, use \fancypagestyle{plain}{...} and that will style e.g. the first pages of chapters.
Including the styling properly in the page required some adjustments to the page layout. You may wish to tweak these e.g. to reduce headsep rather than increasing top, but headheight needs to be at least 29pt to accommodate the header. I've used \fancyheadoffset to accommodate the 3mm shadow, but needed a 1pt fudge factor to make this work.
This simplifies the picture code because we are at the correct position to begin the header and don't have to navigate there relative to the corner of the page.
See comments for more details.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed unless LaTeX is angcient
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[top=1.7cm+15pt,bottom=1.5cm,right=2cm,left=2.5cm,headheight=29pt]{geometry}
% \usepackage{ifthen} % not needed for example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \usepackage{titlesec} % not needed for example
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf[lh]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A)]
      \coordinate(A) at(0,0);
      \shade[top color=gray!80!white,bottom color=white](A) ++(7mm,0pt) -- +(0.6,0)--+(0.4,0.8)--+(-0.3,0.8) -- cycle;
      \draw[color=gray!80!white,line width=1.5pt](A)--++(\textwidth,0pt);
      \fill[color=blue](A)--node[yshift=1mm,pos=0.7,above,color=white,font=\large\bfseries,name=n\thepage]{\thepage}+(0.8,0)--+(1.1,0.8)--+(0.4,0.8)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \fancyhf[rh]{\bfseries\color{blue}\large\rightmark}%
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}% if you want the fancy style to start here
gfjhh;jghcgh
\newpage
hguli
\listoffigures
\newpage
fgdytfu
\chapter{cbvjkdljs}
% \pagestyle{mystyle}% if you want the fancy style to start here
\section{title}
text
\newpage
\section{fgdvvth}
\end{document}



but  The shodow not corect brather

@walid Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean.

I mean that the shodow (wich colored by the gray color ) of pgestyle in right side not in the left side as you did

@walid Should be correct now, sister.

tkak you so much , and I'm your brather not sister  hhh

@walid Perhaps you shouldn't have made assumptions about me, then.
